# How to properly use Vuex getters in Nuxt Vue Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I use **@nuxtjs/composition-api(0.15.1)**, but I faced some problems about accessing Vuex getters in computed().

This is my code in composition API:

```
import { computed, useContext, useFetch, reactive } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

  setup() {
    const { store } = useContext();
    const products = computed(() => {
      return store.getters['products/pageProducts'];
    });
    const pagination = computed(() => {
      return store.getters['products/pagination'];
    });

    useFetch(() => {
      if (!process.server) {
        store.dispatch('products/getPage');
      }
    });

    return {
      products,
      pagination,
    };
  }
```

And the console keeps reporting the warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Write operation failed: computed value is readonly.

found in

---> <Pages/products/Cat.vue> at pages/products/_cat.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

I'm really confused. Because I didn't try to mutate the computed property, just fetching the Data with the AJAX and then simply assign the data to the state in the Vuex mutations.

But I rewrite the code in option API in this way:

```
export default {
  components: {
    ProductCard,
    Pagination,
  },
  async fetch() {
    if (process.server) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('products/getPage');
    }
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.getters['products/pageProducts'];
    },
    pagination() {
      return this.$store.getters['products/pagination'];
    },
  },
};
```

Everything works fine, there's no any errors or warnings. Is it the way I'm wrongly accessing the getters in the composition API or that's just a bug with the **@nuxtjs/composition-api** plugin?

Comment: Although probably unrelated, your `fetch` hook in the options API runs on the server (`if (process.server)`), while the one in the composition API does not (`if (!process.server)`). Can you link to a repro (Codesandbox or GitHub)?

Comment: @tony19 Here's the repo https://shorturl.at/pCOZ6. You're right. It's not related to the **process.server**, and I'm not trying to solve the problem from the server / client aspect also, but still can't figure it out. In my memory, I remember it's fine to access the Vuex getters from the **computed()**.

Comment: @tony19 I found a article which is talking about this kind of error. And use other way to prevent the error. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[fix: computed property hydration doesn't work with useFetch #207](https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/207)

This problem might not can be solved until the Nuxt3 come out.

But I found an alternative solution which use the **middleware()** instead of use **useFetch()**, if you want to the prevent this bug by fetching AJAX data with Vuex Actions and then retrieve it by Getters via the **computed()**.

I make another clearer example which it's the same context like the question above.

~/pages/index.vue :

```
<script>
import { computed, onMounted, useContext, useFetch } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

export default {
  async middleware({ store }) {
    await store.dispatch('getUser');
  },
  setup() {
    const { store } = useContext();
    const user = computed(() => store.getters.user);

    return {
      user,
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

~/store/index.js (Vuex)

```
const state = () => ({
  user: {},
});

const actions = {
  async getUser({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/');
    console.log(data.results[0]);
    commit('SET_USER', data.results[0]);
  },
};

const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = user;
  },
};

const getters = {
  user(state) {
    return state.user;
  },
};
```

If there's something wrong in my answer, please feel free to give your comments.

Comment: FYI `useStore` is now available https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/packages/store

Comment: @Nick: Thanks, this one would be helpful when next time I'm using Nuxt2 with composition api!